# Javascript href change on onChange event

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, href, dom-events, onchange

I got the below script:

```
function sele(dropdownlist, button)
{
    var url = dropdownlist.value;
    if (url !== "")
    {
        button.href = url;
    }
    if  (url === "null")
    {
        button.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
    }
 }
```

The button id is passed by 'button' variable. This script do not pass href to any button. How to make sure the href is changed in the correct button?

Comment: document.getElementById(button) ?

Comment: i don't know your markup so i have hypothesized it in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/BLE5p/20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button element does not have  href attribute. Thus, you might want to do the following:

```
<button id="your_button"> <a id="to_change_url" href="www.hello.com"> 
                          an example </a> </button>
```

Now, rather than trying to access button.href( which should result in error, I think), you can change the anchor element in button. Easy way might be something like this:

```
    var href_to_change=document.getElementById("to_change_url");
    href_to_change.href="WHATEVER URL YOU WANT TO CHANGE TO";
```